# Load testing multiple devices on a server with Firebase

Tags: android, testing, firebase, load-testing, stress-testing

I currently have set up a system with a Node server and Android app clients communicating with a Firebase database for updates. While the system works fine for the one or two simultaneous devices I can run using my Android phone/PC emulator, I need to find some way to stress test the system with numerous client devices sending/receiving updates simultaneously. Is there any way to do this? I've been told that I could use Python in some way, but not much else.

Answer (score 0):

When you mention "stress test the system", I am assuming, you would like to stress the backend servers and understand their performance under load.

1. I would suggest capturing the network traffic between the Android client and the servers using one of the load testing tools like Apache JMeter. This will capture the user transactions on a network level between the Android client and the servers. Once the actions are captured, the script can be enhanced in order to simulate various user-agents (helps in emulating requests from different devices) and the load test can be performed with the recorded JMeter script.

This link might help in understanding the capabilities of JMeter in depth : http://jmeter.apache.org/

However, this has a bit of a learning curve as tool knowledge is necessary.

2. Apart from load testing tools, network sniffing tools such as Fiddler or Wireshark can also be used to capture the network traffic. These tools can also be used to add up concurrency to the backend, however, they do not provide an easy emulation of various devices by manipulating the user agents. But if you want to just validate that the servers are keeping up for a concurrent load, these tools can help and they are not difficult to learn either.

Hope this gives some clarity on your requirement.